# Create a button that populates value in text input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have different components/forms with text inputs/fields in three different files. I want to add a button that populates all the value field with the placeholder hardcoded number/value.

Here is an example of one component in boxform.js

```
const Box = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='col-xs-12'>
        <TextFieldGroup
          label='Width:'
          onChange={props.updateBoundary.bind(null, 0)}
          onBlur={props.onBlurValid.bind(null, 0)}
          field='width'
          error={props.errors[0]}
          value={props.boundaries[0]}
          placeholder='1'
          isDisabled={props.isLoading}
          tooltip={getTooltip('width')} />
      </div>
```

another component in setform.js:

```
const Set = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className='row'>
      <h2>Settings</h2>
      <div className='set-form'>
        <div className='col-xs-12'>
          <TextFieldGroup
            label='Seed:'
            onChange={props.updateSettings.bind(null, 0)}
            onBlur={props.onBlurValid.bind(null, 0)}
            value={props.settings[0]}
            field='seed'
            error={props.errors[0]}
            placeholder='12345'
            isDisabled={props.isLoading}
            tooltip={`Sets.`}/>
        </div>
```

Thank you for the help in advanced!

Comment: What have you tried?  Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt. My guess is you should [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), have a button update that placeholder state, and pass the placeholder state as a prop to the pages/forms/components that need it.

Comment: What is your question? What didn't work?